# custom loss functions with multiple inputs and outputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have a network with two inputs and two outputs as below:

```
image_inputs = Input(shape=(784,))
A_inputs = Input(shape=(780,))
inputs = keras.layers.concatenate([image_inputs, A_inputs])
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(inputs)
outputs1 = Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')(x)
outputs2 = Dense(780, activation='sigmoid')(x)
outputs = keras.layers.concatenate([outputs1, outputs2])
```

My model is as:

```
model = Model([image_inputs, A_inputs], outputs, name='vae_mlp')
```

I want to define some loss functions:

```
def loss_X(inputs,outputs):
    reconstruction_loss = original_dim*binary_crossentropy(inputs[::,0:-(n_d)], outputs[::,0:-(780)])                                              
    return K.mean(reconstruction_loss)

def loss_A(inputs,outputs):
    reconstruction_loss = original_dim*binary_crossentropy(inputs[::,-(n_d):], outputs[::,-(780):])                                              
    return K.mean(reconstruction_loss)

def loss_KL(inputs,outputs):
    A,A_T=triangle(n_z,A_inputs)
    sum_A=tf.reduce_sum(A*A,0)    
    kl_loss =  -0.5*K.sum(1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var)*sum_A, axis=-1)    
    return K.mean(kl_loss)

def loss_total(inputs,outputs):
    reconstruction_loss = original_dim*binary_crossentropy(inputs,outputs)                                              
    A,A_T=triangle(n_z,A_inputs)
    sum_A=tf.reduce_sum(A*A,0)    
    kl_loss =  -0.5*K.sum(1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var)*sum_A, axis=-1)  
    return K.mean(reconstruction_loss + kl_loss)
```

and at the end:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss=loss_total,metrics= [loss_X,loss_A,loss_KL])
history = model.fit([x_train,A_vec],epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, 
                    validation_data=([x_test,A_vec], None))
```

In fact, I want to test a loss function (loss_total) which has some parts and I need to check these individual parts too. But since the input and outputs of the model are multiple, when I want to run the model, I receive this error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The model works for single input and output case, but I do not know how I can run the model in this case?